# Java.Lang.LinkageError when registering for Google Cloud Messaging using Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app built using Xamarin.

I'm trying to add Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) into the app.

I have followed the instructions on the Xamarin website to [Register with GCM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/android/remote_notifications_in_android/#Register_with_GCM).

When this line is called:

```
var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance (this);
```

I am getting the following error:

> Exception of type 'Java.Lang.LinkageError' was thrown.

The full code sample is:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Gms.Gcm;
using Android.Gms.Gcm.Iid;

namespace ClientApp
{
    [Service(Exported = false)]
    class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
    {
        static object locker = new object();

        public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }

        protected override void OnHandleIntent (Intent intent)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
                lock (locker)
                {
                    var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance (this);
                    var token = instanceID.GetToken ("3495XXXXXXXX", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                    Log.Info ("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to change the Linker behavior from "Link SDK assemblies only" to "Don't link". This did resulted in the same error.

The Target framework is set to Android 4.4 (Kit Kat).

The Minimum Android version is 4.1 (API level 16).

The Target Android version is 4.4 (API level 19).

I have these packages included in the project:

- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Gcm
- Xamarin.Android.Support.v4

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, in Xamarin Studio I evently tried removing all the Packages, Components, and References. Then re-downloaded and installed them in the solution. That took care of the linkage error.

I assume that GCM was referencing a newer file version then other components in the project referencing older file versions?